# How to convert one string to another by successive substitutions of characters?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I'm currently trying to design an algorithm that doing such thing:

I got two strings A and B which consist of lowercase characters 'a'-'z'
and I can modify string A using the following operations:

```
1. Select two characters 'c1' and 'c2' from the character set ['a'-'z'].
2. Replace all characters 'c1' in string A with character 'c2'.
```

I need to find the minimum number of operations needed to convert string A to string B when possible.

I have 2 ideas that didn't work

```
1. Simple range-based for cycle that changes string B and compares it with A.
2. Idea with map<char, int> that does the same.
```

Right now I'm stuck on unit-testing with such situation : 'ab' is transferable to 'ba' in 3 iterations and 'abc' to 'bca' in 4 iterations.
My algorithm is wrong and I need some fresh ideas or working solution. 
Can anyone help with this?

Here is some code that shows minimal RepEx:

```cpp
int Transform(string& A, string& B)
{
    int count = 0;

    if(A.size() != B.size()){
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = A.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(A[i]!=B[i]){
           char rep_elem = A[i];
           ++count;
           replace(A.begin(),A.end(),rep_elem,B[i]);
        }
    }

    if(A != B){
        return -1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

How can I improve this or I should find another ideas?

Comment: Show some code...

Comment: asking for ideas is too vague and open-ended, better provide a [mcve] of your idea that didnt work

Comment: Start with looking at the [Hamming Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). It's not quite the same, as there is no sequence of steps that gets you from "aa" to "ab"

Comment: At least: if A contains a letter l at position i and j, it is impossible if word B contains two different letters at i and j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't worry about string operations. Your problem is algorithmic, not textual. You should somehow analyze your data, and only afterwards print your solution.

Start with building a data structure which tells, for each letter, which letter it should be replaced with. Use an array (or `std::map<char, char>` — it should conceptually be similar, but have different syntax).

If you discover that you should convert a letter to two different letters — error, conversion impossible. Otherwise, count the number of non-trivial cycles in the conversion graph.

The length of your solution will be the number of letters which shouldn't be replaced by themselves plus the number of cycles.

I think the code to implement this would be too long to be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for answer, so it doesn't matter in what order the letters are, I just need to build simple comparation matrix using map<char, char>?

Comment: I guess it is important in what order the letters are. But yes, you should first build a conversion table using `map<char, char>` (but you can also use an array `char[26]`), and when you have it, you can forget about the initial string.